# How to delete or drop the column labelled "index" from a dataframe when using to_csv() to save as csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a csv file, cleaning it up a little, and then saving it back to a new csv file. The problem is that the new csv file has a new column (first column in fact), labelled as **index**. Now this is not the row index, as I have turned that off in the to_csv() function as you can see in the code. Plus row index doesn't have a column label as well.

```
df = pd.read_csv('D1.csv', na_values=0, nrows = 139)    # Read csv, with 0 values converted to NaN
df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='any')                       # Delete any rows containing NaN
df = df.reset_index()
df.to_csv('D1Clean.csv', index=False)
```

Any ideas where this phantom column is coming from and how to get rid of it?

Comment: I think you need `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`, but I think you can add sample of your data to question and then it can be more clear...

Comment: @jezrael - That worked! I was thinking that the problem was in `to_csv()` function. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need add parameter `drop=True` to [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

> **drop** : boolean, default False
>
> Do not try to insert index into dataframe columns. This resets the index to the default integer index.